# Interactive input PL/SQL and inserting data

Tags: sql, sqlplus

So I have

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF;
DECLARE
PayNum number := 1;
BEGIN

LOOP
dbms_output.put_line('xx');
dbms_output.put_line('Gathering data to be added to PAYMENT Table');
dbms_output.put_line('____________________________________________');
dbms_output.put_line('xx');

ACCEPT CType CHAR PROMPT 'Please enter credit card type: '; 
ACCEPT CCNum NUMBER PROMPT 'Please enter the credit card number: '; 
ACCEPT pDate DATE FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyy' PROMPT 'Please enter payment date (mm/dd/yyyy): '; 
ACCEPT Amt NUMBER PROMPT 'Please enter amount to be paid: '; 
ACCEPT BankName CHAR PROMPT 'Please enter the credit card number: '; 
ACCEPT AccNum NUMBER PROMPT 'Please enter Bank account number: '; 

INSERT INTO PAYMENT (PayNum, CType, CCNum, BankName, AccNum, pDate, Amt) VALUES ('&PayNum','&CType','&CCNum','&BankName','&AccNum',to_date('&pDate','mm/dd/yyyy'),'&Amt');
PayNum := PayNum + 1;
dbms_output.put_line('');

ACCEPT usroptn CHAR PROMPT 'Do you want to enter another data? (Y/N)';  
dbms_output.put_line('');
EXIT WHEN usroptn = 'N';
END LOOP;

END;
/
```

When I run the script I keep getting:

```
@addpayment.sql
Enter value for paynum: 2
ACCEPT CType CHAR PROMPT 'Please enter credit card type: ';
       *
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-06550: line 11, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CTYPE" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
```

Nowhere have I asked for Paynum on my code. It is just a primary key for the payment table supposed to be increased by one everytime I add a data. How do i get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

ACCEPT is an SQL PLUS command, not a PL/SQL command. Only after all the substitution variables are entered, your PL/SQL block is sent to the PL/SQL engine. Because of these, as far as I know it is not possible to call the SQL PLUS command inside a PL/SQL loop statement.

Comment: I am trying to get input from user and insert that input to a table. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: I assume that you will get a data from user using some form. In this case, you can a create a procedure for the INSERT where you pass the input from user as parameters and call this procedure inside the loop. But in case, you want to do it directly from sql plus, I am afraid I can not help you.